# How to make <RadioButton> stretch to same width as its parent <RadioButtons>?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have a RadioButtons control that stretches to the width of parent controller. However, its children RadioButton only stretches to the width of the Content.

Specifically, I want the textbox beside my second RadioButton to stretch to the remaining with of the panel. How can I achieve this?

```html
<MUXC:RadioButtons  
    Header="General Survey"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <RadioButton x:Name="PhysicalExam_General_Normal" Content="Normal"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="PhysicalExam_General_Abnormal" >
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Abnormal" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </RadioButton>
</MUXC:RadioButtons>
```

In the VS design view, when I click on the RadioButtons parent control, I can see that the width is stretched as expected. However, when I click on each RadioButton, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the Width of RadioButton as the ActualWidth of RadioButtons and then set the HorizontalContentAlignment of RadioButton as Stretch. To set the Width of RadioButton, you could subscribe the SizeChanged event of RadioButtons.

.xaml:

```
<MUXC:RadioButtons Header="General Survey" SizeChanged="RadioButtonsGroup_SizeChanged" x:Name="RadioButtonsGroup">
    <RadioButton x:Name="PhysicalExam_General_Normal" Content="Normal"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="PhysicalExam_General_Abnormal" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Abnormal" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </RadioButton>
</MUXC:RadioButtons>
```

.cs:

```
private void RadioButtonsGroup_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PhysicalExam_General_Abnormal.Width = RadioButtonsGroup.ActualWidth;
}
```

**Update:**

In the default style of RadioButtons, it uses **ColumnMajorUniformToLargestGridLayout** to put each RadioButton. It seems limit the width of RadioButton, you can comment them out to use default layout. In addition, you still need to set the HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment as Stretch. For example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonsStyle1" TargetType="MUXC:RadioButtons">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView" Value="Raw"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MUXC:RadioButtons">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                        <MUXC:ItemsRepeater Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="InnerRepeater" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}">
                             
                        </MUXC:ItemsRepeater>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<MUXC:RadioButtons Header="General Survey" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonsStyle1}" x:Name="RadioButtonsGroup">
    <RadioButton x:Name="PhysicalExam_General_Normal" Content="Normal"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="PhysicalExam_General_Abnormal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Abnormal" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </RadioButton>
</MUXC:RadioButtons>
```

Comment: Is code in cs my only option to achieve this? I was hoping for a xaml solution...